# Add Sum from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, sum

I'm fairly new with PHP and I need help with adding certain row from JSON file.
For instance i have

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => "Computer"
        [price] => 1000

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => "Mouse"
        [price] => 14

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => "Computer"
        [price] => 1500


    )
 [3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => "Mouse"
        [price] => 16

    )
)
```

the output should be

```
Array(
 [name] => "Computer"
 [sum] => 2500
)

 Array(
 [name] => "Mouse"
 [sum] => 30
)
```

I tried using this

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $rows){
$i += $rows['price'];
}
```

but this one basically adds them all.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: That's not JSON. You have a PHP array containing other arrays.

Comment: oops yeah. i mean to say output it as JSON :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code

```
<?php
// make origin
$array_origin = array(
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'Computer','price' => 1000),
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'Mouse','price' => 14),
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'Computer','price' => 1500),
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'Mouse','price' => 16),
);
echo '<pre>' . var_export($array_origin, true) . '</pre><hr>';

// store name-price pair
$stack=array(); 
foreach ($array_origin as $index => $array_part) {
    $stack[$array_part['name']]=array_key_exists($array_part['name'],$stack)?$stack[$array_part['name']]+$array_part['price']:$array_part['price'];
}

// make output
$j=0;
$output=array();
foreach ($stack as $name => $sum) {
    $output[]=array(
        'name' => $name,
        'sum' =>  $sum
    );
    echo '<pre>' . var_export($output[$j], true) . '</pre>';
    $j++;
}
```

## Output

[image]

## Or use json to make origin array

```
$json_str='[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Computer",
        "price":"1000"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Mouse",
        "price":14
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Computer",
        "price":1500
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Mouse",
        "price":16
    }
]';

$array_origin=json_decode($json_str, true);
```

Hope it can help you ~

Answer (score 0):

since you wrote all that out, I guess I can write you a quick loop.

```
 $answer = array();
 foreach($oldarray as $val)
 {
   @$answer[$val['name']] += $val['sum'];
 }
 print_r($answer);
```

It's not the exact answer, but it will get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (array_key_exists($row['name'], $result)) {
        $result[$row['name']]['sum'] += $row['price'];
    } else {
        $result[$row['name']] = [
             'name' => $row['name'],
             'sum' => $row['price'],
        ]; 
    }
}
print_r($result);
```